# TransactionalEventListener won't kick in

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-data, spring-webflux

I have a problem with `@TransactionalEventListener`.

**Given**:

- Kotlin 1.3.50
- Spring Webflux
- Spring Data
- Hibernate 5
- Postgres JDBC (not RDBC!)

**What happens**:

Request to controller was made.

Service did some job within method marked as `@Transactional` an event and published event.

Response returned to client

Event listener marked as `@Async`, `@TransactionalEventListener` and `@Transactional` doesn't kick in.

**What I did:**

I have debugged into service method which publishes an event to find out whether an actual transaction is in progress with the help of some static utility method I don't remember, which told me what I suspected - it is in progress.

Then I enabled debug output to see log saying: `No transaction is in progress. Discarding event.`

I mean, both **publishing** and **consuming** sides do have annotation `@Transactional` on them. **No alterations** to default params of annotations were made.

I have found similar situation in this question [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39260714/transactionaleventlistener-method-not-fired) but no one answered that.

Also, I have read an [article at dzone](https://dzone.com/articles/transaction-synchronization-and-spring-application) but there seems to be no mentioning of my case.

**Workaround:**

I can avoid this by either replacing `@TransactionalEventListener` to `@EventListener` (alas, remove transaction bound processing) or by changing param `fallbackExecute` to `true` which effectively is the same as first solution.

**Suspected parties:**

1. Possibly absence of reactive transaction manager in an webflux environment could be the case? And some weird bug not accounting JpaTransactionManager?

Comment: FYI: I've run into a similar problem and created a Github issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/25805